# Updating values of an obj from an array (beginner)

Tags: c#, .net

I have an array as follow:

```
School[] _schools = new School[MxNr];
```

and the object `School` have a property `Room[].

I have insert all the rooms in a Room Array from `foo.class` as follow:

```
        Rooms[] rooms = new Rooms[NrOfRooms];
        int temp2 = 0;
        foreach (School school in _schools) {
            foreach (Rooms room in school.Rooms) {
                room[temp2++] = room;
            }
        }
```

Now i update the room:

```
Room[0] = new Room(SomeVal);
```

but when i iterate over the School Array i can see that the room is not Updated and still holds on the old value.

EDIT:

```
    public class School {
    public School(string schoolStr, bool IsFirstSchool = false, bool IsLastSchool = false) {
        int nrOfRooms = IsFirstSchool || IsLastSchool ? 1 : 2;
        Rooms = new Room[nrOfRooms];
        Rooms[0] = new Room(someVal);
        Rooms[1] = new Room(someVal);
    }
    public Room[] Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

I want to now why and how i can solve this in c#.

Comment: You have data into `_schools` but unable to update `rooms`, right?

Comment: @X-TECH when i update room from the array rooms, the _schools[i].Room does not get updated. i thought that room will hold a reference to it. im sorry, my explanation is bad

Comment: From where you getting data and how are you putting it into `_schools`?

Comment: How about you post the full code instead of some edited snippets.

Comment: I have a loop in `foo.class` that i use to initialize: `for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
                _schools[i] =  new School(someVal);
            } `

Comment: Show the code of `Shool`?

Comment: Is `Room` a `struct` by any chance?

Comment: Actually, you are creating a new instance of `Room`, and since your `rooms` array and `school.Rooms` are not the same array, the changes to one will not be reflected in the other, unless you are working with an existing `Room` instance. You really should post all the relevant code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DamirArh is there anyway to collect all the room from _school array into an array without creating a new instance?

Comment: @X-TECH copy/paste error, sorry

Answer (score 0):

The best way is `List<Room>` and update into the following way

```
public class School 
{
    public School(string schoolStr, bool IsFirstSchool = false, bool IsLastSchool = false) 
    {
         int nrOfRooms = IsFirstSchool || IsLastSchool ? 1 : 2;
         //set number of rooms in room class
         Rooms = new List<Room>();
         Rooms.Add(new Room(someVal));
         Rooms.Add(new Room(someVal));
    }
    public List<Room> Rooms {get; set; }
}
```

And now, get rooms of all schools

```
var rooms = new List<Room>();
foreach (School school in _schools) 
{
     foreach (Rooms room in school.Rooms) 
     {
          rooms.Add(room);
     }
}
```

To update the room of specific school, you need to set ID in school and room as well

```
var school = _schools.Where(x => x.ShoolId == 2).FirstOrDefault(); //Getting school having Id = 2
if (school != null)
{
    var room = school.Rooms.Where(x => x.RoomId == 1).FirstOrDefault(); //getting room of school with Id = 2 and having roomId = 1 (say)
    if (room != null)
    {
        room = new Room(someValue); //Update Value
    }
}
```

Comment: if I then edit `rooms[0] = new Room(someVal)` the `_school[0].room` still holds the old value

Comment: Use `List<Room>` instead of `Room[]`

Comment: Do you want to change the value of specific room of any school?